# Merge arrays within an array of class

Tags: arrays, swift

The following class has some variables inside of it.

```
class Person {
    var age: Int = 4
    var items = [String]()
} 

var allPeople = [Person]()
var allItems = [String]()
```

Assuming we created initializers for the class and `allPeople` has `n` elements in it, I would like to merge all items for each object into a new array

The problem comes when I try to access each index of `allPeople`, and from there, get the items variable and append it to `allItems`. But I need to specify a number that changes according to the total number of elements. My initial attempt was to use a for loop. Also using `allPeople[allPeople.count - n]`, something similar to this.

Comment: What about `let allItems = allPeople.flatMap { $0.items }`?

Comment: You're not adding/appending them together. Though good usage of `flatmap`. I was using `map` which was incorrect...

Comment: Please describe what exactly you want to achieve, what you have tried and what the current result (issue) is.

Comment: FYI I edited my answer

Comment: What I want to achieve is having an array that has all the objects each person has. After this, I would move on to showing how many repeated objects there are in all the orders, e.g. 2x Radio, 7x Pen, 1x Paper clip, etc. Whenever a new object is added to items, it will update when the user visits the specific ´viewController´ that has the function I was looking for, so it will always be updated. I tried out all the answers and all of them were correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**solution1** (this is the swiftiest way):

```
//if you want to keep adding to the old array
allItems += allPeople.flatMap{$0.items}

//if you want to add into a new array
let newArray = allItems + allPeople.flatMap{$0.items}
```

---

```
// Using 'map' won't work:
allItems = allItems + allPeople.map{$0.items} //error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String]' and '[[String]]'
```

The code above doesn't work because we are adding `[String]]` to `[String]` which the `+` doesn't know how to handle, read:

```
let john = Person()
john.items = ["a", "b", "c"]

let jane = Person()
jane.items = ["d", "e", "f"]

allPeople.append(john)
allPeople.append(jane)

print(allPeople.map{$0.items}) // [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]] <-- [[String]] 
// and obviously can't be added to [String]
```

It is printing Arrays within arrays. So we need to do one more step.

```
let mapped = allPeople.map{$0.items}

print(Array(mapped.joined())) // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

so if we want to use `map`, we should also use `joined`

**solution2** (not very swifty but I just wanted to explain that a `flatMap` is basically a `join` + `map`)

```
let newJoinedMappedArray = allItems + Array(allPeople.map($0.items).joined())
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, if I could up vote you 10 times I would! Thank you for your detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood what your exact problem is but if you just want all of the `item` arrays of all `Person` objects in `allPeople` to be appended to `allItems` you can simply do:

```
for person in allPeople {
    allItems.append(contentsOf: person.items)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
for person in allPeople {
    for item in person.items {
        allItems.append(item)
    }
}
```